# pyLDAvis with Mallet LDA implementation : LdaMallet object has no attribute 'inference'

Tags: gensim, topic-modeling, mallet

is it possible to plot a pyLDAvis with a Mallet implementation of LDA ? I have no troubles with LDA_Model but when I use Mallet I get :

```
'LdaMallet' object has no attribute 'inference'
```

My code :

```
pyLDAvis.enable_notebook()
vis = pyLDAvis.gensim.prepare(mallet_model, corpus, id2word)
vis
```

Answer (score 17):

Run this line to convert the class of your mallet model into a LdaModel before pyLDAvis

[Edit]: edited code to use the inbuilt function in gensim instead. I just tried it but am unable to get meaningful results with the pyLDAvis on a converted mallet model; the topics seem to contain random terms.. Anybody encountered this before?

```
import gensim    
model = gensim.models.wrappers.ldamallet.malletmodel2ldamodel(mallet_model)
```

Got this from the link below, do explore it, lines 565 - 590

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/models/wrappers/ldamallet.py#L359

Comment: Can confirm the seemingly random terms on converted mallet topics. I am currently also looking into it.

Comment: I think the issue has been resolved with the 3.7.0 version of gensim https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/releases/tag/3.7.0

Comment: No more gensim.models.wrappers.

Answer (score 3):

I hope I have helped.

```
from gensim.models.ldamodel import LdaModel
def convertldaGenToldaMallet(mallet_model):
    model_gensim = LdaModel(
        id2word=mallet_model.id2word, num_topics=mallet_model.num_topics,
        alpha=mallet_model.alpha, eta=0,
    )
    model_gensim.state.sstats[...] = mallet_model.wordtopics
    model_gensim.sync_state()
    return model_gensim
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this [blog post](https://jeriwieringa.com/2018/07/17/pyLDAviz-and-Mallet) helpful, directly using the statefile produced by MALLET which is also produced using Gensim's Mallet wrapper.